# number of pairs and max value from a list in c#

Tags: c#, linq

A poker game card representation is like below

```
public class Card
{ 
    public string Rank { get; set; } 
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public char Suit { get; set; }
}
```

From a list of Cards, i have to find number of pairs and max. value from the pairs

Sample values

```
    [
    { "A" , 14, 'D' }
    { "A" , 14, 'H' }
    { "T" , 10, 'D' }
    { "T" , 10, 'S' } 
    { "5" , 5,  'S' } 
    ]
```

In this case 2  pairs [ 1 pair of A and 1 pair of T and max value is 14 ]

Sample values

```
    [
    { "K" , 13, 'D' }
    { "K" , 13, 'H' }
    { "2" , 2, 'D' }
    { "T" , 10, 'S' } 
    { "5" , 5,  'S' } 
    ]
```

In this case only 1 pair of K and   max value is 13

I used below LINQ to find the number of pairs

```
    var pairs_list = hand
        .GroupBy(i => i.Rank)
        .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
        .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Any way to get the value of highest pair with this linq  Or can we make a single query to find no of pairs and max value from the pairs ifany

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add class **Result** like :

```
public class Result
{
    public int NoRanks { get; set; } 
    public int MaxValue { get; set; }
}
```

And change little your code like :

```
var pairsList = hand
    .GroupBy(card => card.Rank)
    .Where(g => g.Skip(1).Any())
    .Select(o => new { Rank = o.Key, Value = o.Max(v => v.Value) });
```

And Build the result by using [*Max*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netcore-3.1) function like :

```
Result result = new Result
{
    NoRanks = pairsList.Count(),
    MaxValue = pairsList.Max(o => o.Value)
};
```

**Demo** : https://dotnetfiddle.net/GitsRb

```
public static void Main()
{
    var hand = new Card[]
    {
        new Card { Rank = "A", Value = 9, Suit = 'D' },
        new Card { Rank = "A", Value = 10, Suit = 'H' },
        new Card { Rank = "T", Value = 12, Suit = 'D' },
        new Card { Rank = "T", Value = 13, Suit = 'S' },
        new Card { Rank = "5", Value = 5, Suit = 'S' },
    };
    
    var pairsList = hand
        .GroupBy(card => card.Rank)
        .Where(g => g.Skip(1).Any())
        .Select(o => new { Rank = o.Key, Value = o.Max(v => v.Value) });
    
    Result result = new Result
    {
        NoRanks  = pairsList.Count(),
        MaxValue = pairsList.Max(o => o.Value)
    };
    
    Console.WriteLine($"Ranks: {string.Join(",", result.NoRanks )} and max value : {result.MaxValue}");

}

public class Card
{
    public string Rank { get; set; } 
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public char Suit { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public int NoRanks  { get; set; } 
    public int MaxValue { get; set; }
}
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Since this is the chosen answer, what happened with single query requirement?

Answer (score 1):

> Any way to get the value of highest pair with this linq

You're really close with your code. You've already selected all the Ranks that are pairs in your hand, so all that's left to do is pick only the largest value.

You should, however, do the grouping based on the integer `Value`, rather than the string `Rank`, as it's easier to find the "larger value" with integers.

```
int largestPairRankInHand = hand
    .GroupBy(card => card.Value)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .Select(g => g.Key)
    .OrderByDescending(val => val)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

The `OrDefault` is just in case there are no items in your hand.

Here's a fiddle example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5Vo45H

Comment: The OP search also the number of pairs not just the max value.

Comment: Sometimes you shouldn't just _give_ the person the fish...

Answer (score 1):

```
 var result = hand
      .GroupBy(i => i.Rank)
      .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
      .Select((g, i) => (value: g.First().Value, index: i + 1))
      .Aggregate((value: 0, count: 0), (p1, p2) => p1.value > p2.value ? (p1.value, p2.index) : (p2.value, p2.index));

 //// or
 //       var result = hand
 //      .GroupBy(i => i.Value)
 //      .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
 //      .Select((g, i) => (value: g.Key, index: i + 1))
 //     .Aggregate((value: 0, count: 0), (p1, p2) => p1.value > p2.value ? (p1.value, p2.index) : (p2.value, p2.index));

Console.WriteLine($" Pair Count: {result.count}, Max Value: {result.value}");
```

Comment: I think, the `pairCount` will give the the count by Rank not between Ranks. for the seconde example the request will give us 2 not 1.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out @Sajid, now it's fixed.